# Exporting code in Isabelle: code equations for instances of a type declared using typedecl

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to export code for functions with quantifiers based on a type declared using typedecl, i.e., something like this:

```
typedecl x

consts set_x1 :: "x set"
consts set_x2 :: "x set"

definition func_1 :: "x set ⇒ bool" where
  "func_1 s ≡ ∀ x ∈ s. x ∈ set_x1 ∧ x ∈ set_x2"

definition func_2 :: "x set ⇒ bool" where
  "func_2 s ≡ ∃ x ∈ s. x ∈ set_x1 ∧ x ∈ set_x2"

export_code
  func_1
  func_2
    in Haskell module_name funcs
```

When trying to export, I get a ''wellsortedness error" because type x has not been defined as belonging to the "equal" class. I've tried to bypass this by using axiomatization:

```
axiomatization where x_equal: "OFCLASS(x, equal_class)"
axiomatization where x_enum: "OFCLASS(x, enum_class)"

instance x :: equal by (rule x_equal)
instance x :: enum by (rule x_enum)
```

However, I still get the following error saying that some code equations for comparing instances of x are missing:

```
No code equations for equal_x_inst.equal_x, set_x2, set_x1
```

For some other functions (not shown here), I also get  messages saying that the equations `enum_x_inst.enum_ex_x` and `enum_x_inst.enum_all_x` are missing (I've also axiomatized x as being of class enum, as shown above).

How can I define these code equations? The ones for the constant sets seem relatively simple, but I'm not sure how to write the lemmas for the others, and I can't find any examples of something similar online.

Comment: Update: I believe I've found out to make the equation for `equal_x` work, like so:

`instantiation x :: equal
begin
  definition equal_x :: "x ⇒ x ⇒ bool" where "equal_x a b ≡ a = b"
  instance by (rule x_equal)
end`

Any help with the equations for `enum_ex_x` and `enum_all_x` would still be appreciated, though.